# Better ordering of mysql/php search results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql/php query which searches through a database and returns matches based on a search string that has been input by the user, it is sorted by title ascending, however we would really like it to be sorted by best match (similar to the way ElasticSearch ranks search results with a score).

Currently, when searching for "quake II" the result list looks like:

```
- Quake
- Quake 4
- Quake II
- Quake III Arena
```

Expected result list must be:

```
- Quake II (corresponding exactly to the search)
- Quake III Arena (containing entirely the search)
- Quake
- Quake 4
```

The current php/mysql query is:

```
$nameKeys = explode(" ", $gamenamethathasbeensearchedfor);
$query = "SELECT id FROM games WHERE GameTitle LIKE '%$nameKeys[0]%'";
for($i = 1; $i <= count($nameKeys); $i++)
{
    if($nameKeys[$i] != "" || $nameKeys[$i] != " " || $nameKeys[$i] != "  " || $nameKeys[$i] != "   ")
    {
        $query .= " AND GameTitle LIKE '%$nameKeys[$i]%'";
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to switch to full-text searching for 'best' match. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Look into Mysql full-text search functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set up a FullText index on GameTitle, then you can take advantage of the power of MySQL's full-text ordering and sorting without having to write some complex query. That is, if you are not using an InnoDB. You could do something like this as well,

```
SELECT id, MATCH (GameTitle) AGAINST ('%$nameKeys[$i]%') AS SCORE FROM games WHERE MATCH (GameTitle) AGAINST ('%$nameKeys[$i]%') limit 10;
```

This should get you pretty close without having to modify your indexes but I would recommend checking out [MySQL Full-text functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! After setting up a full-text index for my column and trying out your query my results are 90% better ordered, so thank you very much for that! The only problem i've found and not been able to resolve is the inclusion of numbers...
For Instance, when executing this query:
`SELECT id, GameTitle, MATCH (GameTitle) AGAINST ('super mario bros. 3') AS SCORE FROM games WHERE MATCH (GameTitle) AGAINST ('super mario bros. 3');`
The results provided are: super mario bros. 2 _then_ super mario bros. 3
Is there anything that could be done about this, as it could really mess up a lot

Comment: Removing the number from the query and appending `AND GameTitle LIKE "%3%"` to the end seems to work, although it is a bit of a hack. I don't mind having to split out the numbers in php and append them to the where clause when generating the query though, if there isn't already a better way to do this??